# Write a FAST word equation solver

Tags: math, fastest-code, puzzle-solver

This question is similar to [Write a word equation solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32475/write-a-word-equation-solver) by David Frank **but different in three important ways:** (1) David asked for just the first solution found, and I am asking for all the solutions.  (2) I am asking to output the time required to solve the puzzle.  And (3), it is a completely different undertaking to write a program designed to be fast compared with one designed to be short.  A brute force method is probably best for code golf, but will not beat my ?amazing? time of 0.15 seconds.  -I say "amazing" only to encourage other to try it out.  I'm sure mine won't be the fastest.

(I'm going to copy a lot of the text from that question.)

**Introduction**

Consider the following example:

```
  CODE
+ GOLF
——————
 GREAT
```

This is an equation where each letter represents a decimal digit and the words represent natural numbers (similar letters represent similar digits and different letters represent different digits). The task is to match each letter with its digit value so that the equation is correct. **One of the four** solutions for the equation above is:

```
  9265
+ 1278
——————
 10543
```

**Your task**

Your task is to write a program or function to **find ALL of the answers** to such a word equation.  Your program should output all the answers and the time it took to find them in seconds.

**Input**

The input will be something like this, two words added together to make a third word.

Example:

1. CODE+GOLF=GREAT
2. AA+BB=CC

Spaces are omitted and only letters between capital A and Z will be used (no special or small letters).  This string can be read from the standard input, from a file, or as a function parameter.

**Output**

The output should look something like this.  To take luck out of the competition, your program must list all the solutions.

```
time = XX.XXX seconds
(1) 9265+1278=10543
(2) 9275+1268=10543
(3) 9428+1437=10865
(4) 9438+1427=10865
```

**Rules**

1. **Similar letters represent similar digits and different letters represent different digits**
2. To make things easier, you can assume that numbers can or don't start with a leading zero, it's up to you.  The four answers I got for the sample problem assume numbers do not start with leading zeros.
3. You can use any language and the standard library of the chosen language (no external libs)
4. You cannot connect to any resources on the internet (why would you anyways?)
5. So the goal here is speed, but of coarse that depends on what computer you use.  In order to account for the different speed of different computers, you could run my example on your computer and then report how many times faster or slower yours is than my sample answer.
6. **Please explain how your code works.**

**Example in JavaScript**

http://goo.gl/TdQczX
[image]
[image]

Comment: For fairness, submissions to fastest-code challenges should all be tested on the *same* machine - which usually means *your* machine. Are you prepared to install all of those submissions on your own machine? Alternatively, another option might be to have everyone run your own solution and their own, the score being the ratio between the two.

Comment: Also I think your example problem may be too small to accurately measure the timing for well-optimised solutions. You might want to provide a larger test case as the benchmark.

Comment: The same question with a different winning criterion [is a duplicate](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/777/194). (Even if the original question has a really stupid winning criterion).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't see how you read that into the answers of that meta question. What they say (and what the usual consensus is) is that it depends on whether answers from one challenge are competitive and valid solutions to the other. Seeing that the other one is code golf, I suspect that no solution will be optimised for efficiency (most of them will probably brute-force it). Hence, I'd say the difference in winning criterion is quite significant.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, it's the plain meaning of the most voted answer, as further explained in Tyzoid's comment on his answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Right, I didn't see his comment. I personally think (and I've seen answers along those lines on meta, too - and the comment with 3 upvotes is one of them) that we should take into account whether any submission from the original challenge would be competitive against new submissions which tackle the new challenge in a way according to the new winning criterion. If three optimised answers to this are posted, who would copy over a golfed brute force solution? I'm pretty sure to win this one, you *do* have to solve it in a novel way.

Comment: (Furthermore, copying a golfed submission into a fastest-code challenge comes very close to justifying a delete-vote for "This does not provide an answer to the question.")

Comment: Hello Martin and Peter.  I am very new to this.  I can say that the answers for the code-golf question seemed to take many seconds or even minutes to run, and they did not find all the solutions.  They just found one.  The method I used in my example is pretty unique - I think.  But then again my code golf answers are typically 5-10 times longer than the shortest ones.  As for judging the speed of an algorithm, I would agree that it's approximate.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, even taking that view, I think this is one of the clearest cases: the scoring system on the other question is so badly exploitable that there's very little stopping an answer from scoring well on both that and speed.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's a fair point, although in that case I'd rather view the old one a duplicate of this one, as this here is definitely the more interesting challenge (answers to which can be submitted to the other one by encoding it in a whitespace string). One more thing about Tyzoid's opinion: there is a reasonable chance that his strong opinion and the upvotes were correlated to the fact that the two winning criteria in question *were* much more similar than code-golf vs fastest-code.

Comment: Also, for comparison sake, my answer can be run on anyone's computer because it's JavaScript on a web page -not that this completely solves the problem.  (I'll add a link to it.)

Comment: Can multiple letters have the same digit? or are there only a maximum of 10 different letters per equation.

Comment: The "O" in GOLF and the "O" in CODE have the same value. This is what David meant by "Similar letters represent similar digits and different letters represent different digits."  Also two different letters can not have the same value.

Comment: I adjusted rule number 5 to try to standardize the speed of different computers.  You can answer in seconds if you want to be general/approximate, or you can answer as a factor of the sample answer if you want to be more precise.

Comment: Why not use most elegant solution? This is determine by popularity, also is applicable to each language.

Comment: @JeffSB If I had ABCDEFGHIJK, only 10 of 11 letters would be able to be assigned digits. Would K have one of the previously assigned digits, or can there only be 10 letters?

Comment: Adam, I'm fine with most votes.  It's about the fun of it.

Comment: Ourous, You can only have ten different letters, but letters can be repeated.  CODE+GOLF=GREAT has 13 letters, but only 10 unique letters - so it works.

Comment: @AdamSpeight Because why turn something into a popularity contest if you don't have to? (@JeffSB, please, please, stick to fastest code.)

Comment: Okay, fastest code it is.

Comment: I inserted the 2nd paragraph to address the duplicate issue.

Answer (score 6):

## Python3, 0.03 seconds:

```py
def f(a, b, r, c = {}, s = [], k = 0, l = [], A = [], B = []):
   if not a and not b:
      yield f"{''.join(map(str, A))}+{''.join(map(str, B))}={''.join(map(str, l))}"
      return
   for x in c.get(a[-1], range(10)):
      if a[-1] in c or x not in s:
         _c, _s = {**c, a[-1]:[x]}, s+[x]
         for y in _c.get(b[-1], range(10)):
             if b[-1] in _c or y not in _s:
                n_c, v = {**_c, b[-1]:[y]}, k+x+y
                n_s = _s+[y]
                if a[:-1] and b[:-1]:
                    _v, _k = v%10, v//10
                    if [_v] == n_c.get(r[-1], [_v])and (r[-1] in n_c or _v not in n_s):
                        yield from f(a[:-1], b[:-1], r[:-1], {**n_c, r[-1]:[_v]}, n_s+[_v], _k, [_v]+l, [x]+A, [y]+B)
                else:
                    if len(str(v)) == len(r):
                        F = 1
                        for J, K in zip(r[::-1], str(v)[::-1]):
                            if n_c.get(J, [int(K)]) == [int(K)] and (J in n_c or int(K) not in n_s):
                               n_c[J] = [int(K)]
                               n_s = n_s + [int(K)]
                            else:
                               F = 0
                               break
                        if F: yield from f(a[:-1], b[:-1], '', n_c, n_s, 0, [v]+l, [x]+A, [y]+B) 
            
t = time.time()
result = [*f('CODE', 'GOLF', 'GREAT')]
print(time.time() - t)
print(result)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNb5tAEL3zK0aRKlhDHFu9REg@2I1dyWljKe0lQgiBvaTUeEELQaZWfrs7swu1G39yYHZnZ@a9eTuQ1@WvTHy@z@V2m6zyTJZQJituLHgMsRU6EDkgHZjDADbvDhRoPd@BJdqeA2mzHTZ2pCxzDQBIYhBZCSGEYqFWkXLjUyc8XUB8szHN7u8sEdYqzK2iRJghY@/2oXuE7sGhO0X3TVNT8vJNCtrEmYQ1JALm3VdeWqF320dmMhSv3Or3GGtZID91pkJBJRFL3BVtCD7B3IGAut50OrhUGa639kkLG@0uknBrSg80cHQKGP7hRy1@oAjULYGg@BCLjyAmlSZCy0gzqYnJ0l7b9ZEM4h0gzdo/OFTduwRP1xOp5SGoUqBCBei@q099vPLq7q7fOxqIJb2g8mEwILJKA6k1IDcjHO2gFoVuOajanpEtO05gb2RktqKpVGydhjVK3FhURqkktTQIitoIEgCX1IRmYqdo1749RFP79ogdoPK04O6pHlMuaPysijFqlbbyDPMJKtc/eUpDM3XgkRT4k@Soj6t70Qh6d6Z6w6nVG0t5iSitR@Yrcu1GXbI13RNeH1wn/m4CvakPu6qXE2gA6W1fl3Na9w@C9i4FRZKHS@OMYhP3/EyZpqM/OaTv0K/OOzI4/1c1jBKp0d@zSy@LGZIXbyk5vU5smV9mD2Osan6dfZso@zwe/jRRklySOHuJcAsla9y6BrtQ@8f46YFqfp89j7V9Gr9cW3u7/Qs)

Comment: I think this answer qualifies for 400 rep from [this bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20846) and 500 rep if you add an explanation.

Comment: does not work on 
print([*f('FIFTY', 'STATES', 'AMERICA')])

Answer (score 4):

## C++, 10000× faster (~20 µs)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>

// digits
typedef int digit_t;
const digit_t BASE = 10;
typedef unsigned digit_mask_t;
inline char format_digit(digit_t d) { return '0' + d; }

// letters
typedef int letter_t;
const letter_t ALPHABETSIZE = 26;
typedef unsigned letter_mask_t;
inline bool is_letter(char c) { return unsigned(c - 'A') < 26u; }
inline letter_t parse_letter(char c) { return letter_t(c - 'A'); }

// terms
typedef int term_t;
inline term_t term_abs(term_t x) { return x < 0 ? -x : x; }


bool parse_formula(const char* formula, term_t coeffs[ALPHABETSIZE], letter_mask_t* ppresent, letter_mask_t* pleading) {
    // Convert BA+BB=CCC into A + 21*B - 111*C = 0.
    letter_mask_t present = 0, leading = 0;
    const char* p = formula;
    term_t side = +1, place = +1;
    for (;;) {
        const char* r;
        for (r = p; is_letter(*r); ++r) {}
        if (p < r)
            leading |= letter_mask_t(1) << parse_letter(*p);
        for (const char* q = r; q != p; --q) {
            letter_t l = parse_letter(q[-1]);
            coeffs[l] += place;
            present |= letter_mask_t(1) << l;
            place *= BASE;
        }
        p = r;
        switch (*p++) {
            case 0:
                *ppresent = present; *pleading = leading; return true;
            case '+':
                place = +side; break;
            case '-':
                place = -side; break;
            case '=':
                if (side < 0)
                    return false;
                place = side = -1;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}

struct Var {
    digit_t value;
    term_t coeff;
    digit_t minval;  // 0 or 1
    letter_t name;
};

class Solver {
    const char* formula;
    letter_t num_vars;
    Var vars[BASE];
    void solve2(Var*, digit_mask_t, term_t, term_t);
public:
    bool solve(const char* formula);
};

bool Solver::solve(const char* formula) {
    this->formula = formula;
    term_t coeffs[ALPHABETSIZE] = {0};
    letter_mask_t present, leading;
    if (!parse_formula(formula, coeffs, &present, &leading))
        return false;
    // sort the used letters by magnitude of their coefficient
    letter_t letters[BASE];
    letter_t num_vars = 0;
    for (letter_t i = 0; i < ALPHABETSIZE; ++i) {
        if (present & (letter_mask_t(1) << i)) {
            if (num_vars == BASE)
                return false;
            letters[num_vars++] = i;
        }
    }
    if (num_vars == 0)
        return false;
    this->num_vars = num_vars;
    std::sort(letters, letters + num_vars, [&](letter_t a, letter_t b) { return term_abs(coeffs[a]) < term_abs(coeffs[b]); });
    // initialize tables
    term_t bounds[2] = {0};
    for (letter_t i = 0; i < num_vars; ++i) {
        vars[i].name = letters[i];
        vars[i].minval = digit_t((leading >> letters[i]) & 1);
        term_t coeff = vars[i].coeff = coeffs[letters[i]];
        bounds[coeff > 0] += coeff * (BASE - 1);
    }
    // call the recursive solver
    solve2(vars + num_vars - 1, 0, bounds[0], bounds[1]);
    return true;
}

void Solver::solve2(Var* pos, digit_mask_t digits_used, term_t lower_bound, term_t upper_bound) {
    term_t coeff = pos->coeff;
    digit_t d = BASE - 1, e = pos->minval;
    // adjust bounds to reflect a digit equal to BASE-1, instead of anything in [0,BASE)
    if (coeff < 0)
        upper_bound += coeff * d;
    else
        lower_bound += coeff * d;
    do {
        if (lower_bound <= 0 && upper_bound >= 0 && !(digits_used & (digit_mask_t(1) << d))) {
            pos->value = d;
            if (pos == vars) {
                // print the solution
                char digit_chars[ALPHABETSIZE];
                for (letter_t i = 0; i < num_vars; ++i)
                    digit_chars[vars[i].name] = format_digit(vars[i].value);
                for (const char* p = formula; *p; ++p)
                    putchar(is_letter(*p) ? digit_chars[parse_letter(*p)] : *p);
                putchar('\n');
            } else {
                solve2(pos - 1, digits_used | (digit_mask_t(1) << d), lower_bound, upper_bound);
            }
        }
        lower_bound -= coeff;
        upper_bound -= coeff;
    } while (--d >= e);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int code = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        puts(argv[i]);
        clock_t t = clock();
        code |= !Solver().solve(argv[i]);
        t = clock() - t;
        printf("%f\n", double(t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
    return code;
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVfBbttGED1Ll_7C2EUtUhQdyYeiMC0VtuqmRQ04iIMeqggCRa6kbSiS5pKO00Rf0ksuPfbUv-nXdGZ3uVwqEtCDIHJ2dnZm3szb4Z9_R3lSCfot1lH0-fNfVbnyv_v3K-9rnkZJFTO4EmXMs_PNpNuISr5lbUmYrLOCl5vtpNt98QJivual6JYfchazFfC0VKJFGXSjLBXmFW6uH25hDKNhYLSrVPB1ymKtsw3FO9rH04SnDKJNWMAqK7ZhuZAKTm0qduEjFKysihR6wx54EAewk_4krCxZ0XZIyRqP6ne4vnv10_XN7ZuHn38j1y6-PeCaVt7zbZllCXCxUKuOdDWyvKq3OxH40LvuuXCF5ivyUlswTuRhIdhRQ7WaMVQHitJtO0ySWC6qV_UXLoWj358t48_o1RC-B_8ZLuFZWu7KyJRPlPsqCR2VNXKtD1o2qM1HGVutxMzO5HzQTlof8rxggqXllwsJC2OertGnbgeDmmbpEyuoVrybm_F0OqXAMrhGhC9G_RtMwWg06k8Rq-F5t9MyBvoMWqNzpF16CbodO4AcZToIXNFRCI6lPQZvNECXwkg94zIqghME0r2WlQIX1WqBunlg1UK_QIw8r8BNO1TiK3ByzHPh4kun9uvTuJ0KZ4QVctWuhX7umlPssx_xxCLAvxN5su8_Kv86pqQS8sk29TjzR3NpraMBS-bgjVWwUlxn74hjiVKSuemPZS-ThALMpTv4IN7zMtoA-u152qMoFAyGl_TY6ecNQvopgH7eIKWfgro6y6JSvkkrPa-n7BiACLQAlgUL31lq_p6af1htrNUIHok-doJEqNPRx6_CRKjzjS1dJv5IiRub2IJhlZTK5P5-TNKui60lMKCohF-xwzE5NZc9hYkM0-6noFne8hQ1AgDsjiFgKYy6Dc5puMWtu6DbjZJQCHjIEmwfsn6gZQN7Y7VdPGGBoIzcoccZYTpHwVPGYxBk6cLBxf6gxc5149f_WFR5tUx4hLFL6pA7D1GGqzyVSsrRy8vjyhREueHCn2jJobY9RD6o93G4C46wg2EGVCDoT9pMZ9hNWR7Amdl3VlMVVckexIiNyJC2yg2DSphLQ8DyA2zDdcpLujqzFSnwQhnnEUe7FiZ6j8HhC7A0mUk-MItcSvHvqnWbEQNx1YSSgHTnnZmdre7mru5X0m2OU33uHizqTu1ure55lHpuCv4LW8MDiVMIWwFahYnTCBVIUWqXxcCk1TN6A5idzZtshIPmXl1aF525BHXFhHO6kPelyzndrq4ClCNqPEz4H3iThsuECVN1y6xKYzG7aErtKCQmnAYO2Wt8fk69C2ODOifIzaLqelzWNOA4NU1OJtYWFwEdSVq3GwK31Xbq95r0zU55mg5EKU1gKK8E9dYHR85rvrK_kymJwiSRNV6wqCoEf2Kq2wsES_GFRLFBh7YP6DrWJw3n5lFdRy2mR4qU3NMiB8VBkGeizUN68FxQu5lhJMneIwLyBCOr8ryWKVJpZwoN-5N90o1Blb7yn9VqmotlLsL490rUtQA4oxRslTCk91B5BuyxQgRxgQz5aIYjySGIRANh-gErH9HkKcyGA91l1DDKLX0XWa7byMToAcP-QQ0r4H2NODPdb2tdYW3C2ZmdFpho2YljJZW4wk64porYrblCpkTeXlSnQU0fKKZuJ_i1IqUrL-SEupEVU5U8S-WKHHfVKfS4R-Xqlv2fzaXubtuW3WlzfX2YT4l6UQbgWicdmxVxVKGDcn1QXpWk41hzX-7iKG07sD_NzXHK1kNdY6D3Nu0p0Q4IVZ0zXfyUTVmENjKfjiAzaDeAXfnqAD2x2fXgj83I0ao3S76D9xueMHB8X9YKpYu-FAjRbchThx7CYh0N1Cdbv48vTxJ8WokyOTSZq4tkhOJIoUgbLXrEtAiH9hO9kVNRkkXU7zQ2ymdHickqDqsnii0c91zNEvZWawsmsSSRrMOVc_rN6m16ilnNcHZhTukCfnvc3U9_eVi8un29eLidatbTBEWnYdDqm1l_Ov8zO53e_3Drvby_-3H88vXt9ZvTuV76Dw)

This is roughly 10,000 times faster than JeffSB's solver and 2,500 times faster than Ajax1234's solver on my machine on the problem `CODE+GOLF=GREAT`. The speed ratio varies widely with the problem. For `FIFTY+STATES=AMERICA`, the JeffSB/me ratio is 25,000, while for `CORRECTS+REJECTED=MATTRESS` it's about 25.

The algorithm is quite different. Neither JeffSB nor Ajax1234 explained theirs, but it appears they both do digitwise addition from right to left. This program converts a problem like `TO+GO=OUT` into a formula like \$-98 O + 10 G - 10 U + 9 T = 0\$, with the terms sorted by absolute value. For each term from left to right, for each possible value of that digit, it computes upper and lower bounds for the sum by assuming that every later digit is 0 or 9. If the bounds include 0 then it recurses.

Since it doesn't cost any time, this program supports a more general set of alphametics with arbitrarily many terms on both sides of the `=`, and subtraction as well as addition. It can very quickly solve problems like `NINETEEN+NINETEEN+TEN+TEN+TEN+TEN+NINE+NINE+NINE+NINE+NINE+ONE+ONE+ONE+...=THOUSAND` where there are 877 `ONE`s.

I tried computing slightly more sophisticated bounds, and rewriting the recursive function as an iterative one, but both changes only improved performance by 1-2%, and complicated the code, so I reverted them.

<sup>(Sources for example problems: [Mike Keith](http://www.cadaeic.net/alphas.htm), [Michael Hartley](https://www.dr-mikes-math-games-for-kids.com/cryptarithms.html))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <5ms

```
def solver(eqn, soln_format = "eqn"):
    #get weights
    weight = -1
    weights = {}
    for char in reversed(eqn):
        if char=='=':
            weight=1
            continue
        if char=='+':
            if weight>0:
                weight=1
            else:
                weight=-1
            continue
        if char not in weights:
            weights[char] = 0
        weights[char]+= weight
        weight*=10
    
    assert len(weights) <= 10
    weights_sorted = list(weights.values()) + [0]*(10-len(weights.values()))
    weights_sorted.sort()
    
    _, order = zip(*sorted(zip(weights_sorted, range(10)), key=lambda x: abs(x[0]), reverse=True)) #abs sorted order
    order_list = [num - sum(i<num for i in order[:idx]) for idx, num in enumerate(order)] #because indexes change
    order_list = order_list[:len(weights.values())] #to ignore zeros
    order_list.reverse() #to pop and append like a stack
        
    for soln in backtrack(0, weights_sorted.copy(), order_list, list(reversed(range(10))), []):
        weights_copy = weights.copy()
        weight_soln_pair = [(weights_sorted[i],num) for i,num in zip(order, soln)]
        assert sum(i*j for i,j in weight_soln_pair) == 0, "Major error"
        final_soln = {}
        for weight_val, soln_val in weight_soln_pair:
            for char, weight in weights_copy.items():
                if weight == weight_val:
                    final_soln[char] = soln_val
                    del weights_copy[char]
                    break
                    
        if soln_format == "eqn":
            #CONVERT TO EQN
            eqn_copy = eqn
            for k, v in final_soln.items():
                eqn_copy = eqn_copy.replace(k, str(v))
            yield eqn_copy
        elif soln_format == "dict":
            yield final_soln
        
def backtrack(val, weights, test_order, remaining, soln):
    #Check if end
    if len(test_order)==0:
        if val==0: 
            yield soln
        return False
    #Check if possible
    if sum([i*j for i,j in zip(remaining, reversed(weights))]) + val < 0: #max
        return False
    if sum([i*j for i,j in zip(remaining, weights)]) + val > 0: #min
        return False
    #Backtrack for each digit
    order = test_order.pop()
    weight = weights.pop(order)
    for i, num in enumerate(remaining):
        del remaining[i]
        yield from backtrack(val+num*weight, weights, test_order, remaining, soln + [num])
        remaining.insert(i, num)
    weights.insert(order, weight)
    test_order.append(order)
    return False
```

does pretty much the same as benrg's answer, but in python and does not remove the solutions with leading zeros

```
%%timeit -n 1 -r 1
print([*solver('CODE+GOLF=GREAT')])
```

---

```
['9428+1437=10865', '9438+1427=10865', '9265+1278=10543', '9275+1268=10543', '8653+0671=09324', '8673+0651=09324', '8643+0672=09315', '8673+0642=09315', '8612+0635=09247', '8632+0615=09247', '7642+0651=08293', '7652+0641=08293', '6918+0934=07852', '6938+0914=07852', '6918+0925=07843', '6928+0915=07843', '5928+0943=06871', '5948+0923=06871', '3857+0862=04719', '3867+0852=04719', '3612+0685=04297', '3682+0615=04297', '2918+0956=03874', '2958+0916=03874', '2918+0947=03865', '2948+0917=03865', '2846+0851=03697', '2856+0841=03697']
4.63 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

notebook [link](https://github.com/arrmansa/fast-word-equation-solver/blob/main/fast-word-equation-solver.ipynb)